# How to flatten a list to return a new list with all the elements?

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function called flatten_list that takes as input a list which may be nested, and returns a non-nested list with all the elements of the input list.

My code:

```
def flatten_list(alist):
    """
    >>> flatten_list([1,2,3])
    [1, 2, 3]
    >>> flatten_list([1, [2,3], [4, 5], 6])
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    """
    flat_list = []
    for element in alist:
        flat_list += element
    return flat_list
```

This code works for lists with strings, but not integer values. How can I change the code so that it works for both?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, this would be done recursively, for example:

```
def flatten(input_, output=None):
    if output is None:
        output = []
    if isinstance(input_, basestring):
        output.append(input_)
    else:
        for item in input_:
            try:
                flatten(item, output)
            except TypeError:
                output.append(item)
    return output
```

This will work with any combination of iterable containers (e.g. `set`, `list`, `tuple`, `dict` (keys only)) and contents (e.g. `int`, `float`, `str`), using the common [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2.7/glossary.html#term-eafp) Python style. Note the specific exception for strings, which you probably don't want to be unpacked!

A few examples of usage:

```
>>> flatten([1, [2, [3, [4, 5], 6], 7], 8])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> flatten([1, "foo", ["bar", 2], 3])
[1, 'foo', 'bar', 2, 3]
>>> flatten([1, (2, 3), {4: 5}])
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> flatten("hello")
['hello']
```

And what happens with non-iterables as direct arguments:

```
>>> flatten(1)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    flatten(1)
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 4, in flatten
    for item in input_:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as:

```
a = [1, [2,3], [4, 5], 6]

def flatten(l,result = []):
    if isinstance(l, list):
        for i in l:
            flatten(i)
    else:
        result.append(l)
    return result

>>> print flatten(a)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

This will works for even deeper nesting levels:

```
>>> print flatten([1, [2, [3, 4]]])
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

[Demo](http://repl.it/SIO)

Comment: Firstly, `type(l) == int` should really be `isinstance(l, int)`, which handles inheritance better. Secondly, this *only* works if the final output is `int`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, Thank you. I have updated my answer. It works better now.

Answer (score 0):

using collections.Iterable

```
from collections import Iterable
def flatten(items):
    for elem in items:
        if isinstance(elem,Iterable) and not isinstance(elem,str):
            for sub_elem in flatten(elem):
                yield sub_elem
        else:
            yield elem




 In [15]:   print list(flatten((1, (2,3), [4, 5],{10,11,12}, 6)))
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 6]


 In [16]: print list(flatten((1, (2,3), (4,5,6), 6)))
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6]

 In [17]: print list(flatten([1, "foo", ["bar", 2], 3]))
 [1, 'foo', 'bar', 2, 3]
```